# Not updating locations in service thread

Tags: android, gps, android-service, android-location

I am using background service to get location coordinates in specific interval of time and performing update operations to database. I already searched many similar problems but not helped.

I created thread within the service to perform this operation. **But i am stuck when** service is not updating locations. I found that method "requestLocationUpdates()" is not getting called within thread. In fact i used Toast method within thread that also not working.

May be the problem is in "Context" argument that passed into both above methods. But i am not able to correct this code.

The main concern is to get accurate locations from thread in service and update them to server. Accounting this part please show me the correct code or any other source that illustrate same functioning in better way. Here is my code...

```
public class IcareService extends Service implements LocationListener
{   

 private Handler mUserLocationHandler = null;
 Thread triggerService; 
 LocationManager lm;
 Criteria criteria;
 String provider,lat,lon,rid;



    @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onDestroy();
 Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping  Service and so thread...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 mUserLocationHandler.getLooper().quit();
 }


  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
     //Not implemented...this sample is only for starting and stopping services.
     //Service binding will be covered in another tutorial
     return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
            super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
      //Announcement about starting
      Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Service...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      addLocationListener();            
      return START_STICKY;
    }




    private void addLocationListener()
    {
        triggerService = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
         try{
              Looper.prepare();//Initialise the current thread as a looper.

              mUserLocationHandler = new Handler();

              lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

             // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
             Criteria c = new Criteria();
             criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE); 

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            final String PROVIDER = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);

        //This 2 below statement not executing...       
          lm.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, 7000, 5, IcareService.this);
      Toast.makeText(IcareService.this, "Updating Location...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Thread.sleep(7000);                    
            Looper.loop();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "LocationThreadicare");
        triggerService.start();
    }


@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// Getting latitude of the current location
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
lat = Double.toString(latitude);

 // Getting longitude of the current location
 double longitude = location.getLongitude();
 lon= Double.toString(longitude);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Gt loc nw sendng to srvr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     SendtoServer();            

}


      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 


    SendtoServer(){
    .............}
}
```

Comment: Hello aseem, i am facing a similar issues. have you any solution to solve this problem?. Please let me know, i stuck this problem from last one week but no luck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @amolsawant96Kuli Hi amol i am really sorry for not replying as i was not being active user for 3 months.....yes i had solved this problem 3 mnths back but rite now i forgot almost everything bcz i have completely change my track of profession from android developer....i m sooo sorry for that. And i hope you had already solved this problem before. All i can say best wishes for ur life.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Toast for debugging (it, by the way, requires running on the UI thread, a.k.a. the main thread), use

```
Log.d("--------","\n\n-------"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"\n\n");
```

Add such logging to `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()`
and the places of interest, and you will see what happens.

Use `adb logcat` to see the logs.